# How can a batch file locate where it is located?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, locate

How can a batch file by itself see where it is located?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

%0 is the name of the file. %~dp0 will be the absolute location of the file, with d being the drive, p being the path, and 0 being the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Just call "cd"

```
set WORKING_DIRECTORY=%cd%
```

Used to be %~dp0, but that's not working for me in Vista.

Comment: That's not the location of the cmd file, it's the working directory when you run it, which is not the same thing: "cd \" followed by "\directory\x.cmd" will have %cd% set to "\", not "\directory".